# Azure's application service has a Bug

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service, file-permissions, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a azure service running wordpress.

Someday, I updated a plugin (Yoast SEO) and stopped work. Azure's KUDU panel cannot shows files.

Look:
[image]

I can list using command *ls-l*, but KUDU panel no.

I tryied *chmod*, *chown* and nothing.

More special is when I changed directory to this folder and receveive response my session is expired. But it is not. I get use other feature with same session.

[image]

If I access using direct URL, I receive: 
*"You do not have permission to view this directory or page"*

I have a Microsoft support but it not helps.

Anyone, please!

Comment: Log out, clear your cookies and try again.

Comment: I tried it. Nothing happens.

Comment: Have you solve it now?

Comment: Not yet. On the contrary, I have another service instance with the same error. MS support continues to work on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft support has concluded that there is a plugin that can be used in the Application Service called [Composer](https://github.com/SyntaxC4-MSFT/ComposerExtension) that does not allow the word "vendor" and with this, the error.

[image]

[image]

We have disabled this extension and the site has returned to normal operation.

Hope it helps.